# Set the logic of value usage

Tags: algorithm, function, methods, foreach

I want to implement a logic "If this_field is initialized, then: get its value, else: use the average value amongst all the initialized this_field in all listed objects instead". I know I can check the None in Foreach cycle, using specific field, but I want one function/interface/smth to use on all the fields (there are 50+ of them, so overloading might be too long, and too strict, in case I'll add more fields to my class).
For examle:

```
Foreach (City thiscity in Cities) {
    thiscity.PolutionRoughEstimation = thiscity.PolutionData.MetalsPortion != None ?
    thiscity.PolutionData.MetalsInAirPortion : 
    AverageKnown(Cities, Object.PolutionData.MetalsPortion) ;
}
```

Yet, I do not whant to write the overloading of AverageKnown for all parameters. I also don't want to write the same Foreach loop for each field. I just whant my system to use the average value of this group, whenever I have no data for it. There might be a way to write it once, but I just cannot figure it out.
Help me, please.

Comment: This question looks highly language-specific so you should indicate what programming language you are using.

Comment: I was going to use either cpp or c#. But I am just at the start of project, so I can switch to something else, like Python, in case it have the thing I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you can do this, by simply use `Average` method. See this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<City> cities = new List<City>();
        cities.Add(new City { Polution = 1, OtherField = 1 });
        cities.Add(new City { Polution = 5, OtherField = 5 });
        cities.Add(new City { OtherField = 2 });

        double? ave = cities.Average(c => c.Polution);
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int? Polution;
        public int? OtherField;
    }
```

The value of `ave` is `3` not `2`.

and so, **it depends on the implementation of your programming language/lib**.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about lambdas. Thank You. 
And can I use it to somehow fill all the empty fields, not only Polution?
Like:

`foreach a in cities:{
    foreach f in City.Fields:{ // what should I write instead this line?
        if (a.f == None): { 
            a.f = cities.Average(c => c.f);}}}
`

Comment: @Nick, I do not think so. You will need to use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Now I figured it out how to use reflections with expressions to fill the missing data

```
using System.Reflection;
public void FillGapInData(ref List<City> cities) 
        {
            foreach (var city in cities)
            {
                Type t = city.GetType();
                PropertyInfo[] parameteres = t.GetProperties(); 
                foreach (var parameter in parameteres)
                {
                    if (((double?)parameter.GetValue(city)).Equals(null))
                    {
                        double? a = cities
                            .Average(c => (double?)parameter.GetValue(c));
                        parameter.SetValue(city, a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

More accurate version, to ensure we do not spoil our string properties, and with -1 as an explicit mark for "missing data":

```
using System.Reflection;
public void FillGapInData(ref List<City> cities) 
{
    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
        Type t = city.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] parameteres = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (var parameter in parameteres)
        {
            if (parameter.PropertyType == typeof(double?)) //check we have a number here
            if ((((double?)parameter.GetValue(city)) == -1) || //check for -1 reserved mark
                (((double?)parameter.GetValue(city)).Equals(null))) 
            {
                double? a = cities
                            .Where(c => ( ((double?)(parameter.GetValue(c)) != -1) 
                                     && !(((double?)(parameter.GetValue(c))).Equals(null)))) //I couldn't stop
                            .Average(c =>  (double?)(parameter.GetValue(c)));
                parameter.SetValue(city, a);
             }
         }
     }
}
```